# Select and order from just 1 row

Tags: mysql

i've got a table in my database with about 50 cols. Now i want to write a Select to order dates from 1 row.

Example Table:

```
ID | foo1   |  f1_rank |  foo2    |  f2_rank | foo3    | f3_rank
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | bar1   |  3       |  bar2    |  1       | bar3    | 2
2  | babar1 |  1       |  barbar2 |  3       | barbar3 | 2
```

The select should order the foo1, foo2 and foo3 cols based on the "f*_rank",
like this:

```
For ID1:
bar2
bar3
bar1
```

For ID2: barbar1, barbar3, barbar2

I dont know how to reach that. Is the right way to interlace some selects-statements?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Database should be designed accordingly to your needs: if you need to retrieve that data probably you should have designed db differently...

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing

Comment: I know, it's a terrible structure and i didn't planned it. But it's a running project and i have to fix this problem :(

Comment: Well, you're just going to hit the next problem, and the next, until you fix the project.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: It should be something like "SELECT foo1, foo2, foo3 FROM _table_ ORDER by f%_rank DESC".... ok, i now know whats Strawberry means, u are right bro.. but our boss isn't that cooperative, spending time on running projects while the client is an old cheapskate :O i will try to convince him.

Comment: let your boss know the old (bad) database structure will cost him money on development time because it's not easy do get things done on the currect structure..

Answer (score 0):

Mysql cannot sort in row but you could unpivot then pivot/conditional aggregation

```
select id,
         max(case when rnk = 1 then foo else null end) foo1,
         max(case when rnk = 2 then foo else null end) foo2,
         max(case when rnk = 3 then foo else null end) foo3
from
(
select id, foo1 foo,f1_rank rnk from t
union all
select id, foo2,f2_rank from t
union all
select id, foo3,f3_rank from t
) s
group by id;

+------+--------+---------+---------+
| id   | foo1   | foo2    | foo3    |
+------+--------+---------+---------+
|    1 | bar2   | bar3    | bar1    |
|    2 | babar1 | barbar3 | barbar2 |
+------+--------+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For fifty columns that's going to be a bit of a bore.